# list of specific field of Documents in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

is there any solution to get a list of specific field of Documents in mongoengine 
like getting list of Documents we use `.objects` function 
or I have to use loop to generate a list of specific field of Documents ? 

for example I have this `Document`:

```
class User(Document):
    email = StringField()
    name = StringField()
```

and I have list of emails of all users in `string`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get list of specific values with this

```
User.objects.filter(....).values_list('email')
```

**OR**

```
User.objects.filter(....).scalar('email')
```

For more details read [mongoengine docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.scalar).

Comment: any performance difference between using a {"field": 1} in the .find?

Comment: actual link for docs - http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.scalar